# Setting background URI image not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, viewmodel

I have two background images for a window depending on which navigation page the user is on within the window. The images are located within my project folder at the location:

```
/Resources/Images/MyImage1.jpg
```

If I use the IDE to select a fixed background image then the xaml file is updated with:

```
<NavigationWindow.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Blah.MyApp;component/Resources/Images/MyImage1.jpg" />
</NavigationWindow.Background>
```

This shows the image correctly.

However, as I want the images to switch, I have created a ViewModel (which implements INotifyPropertyChanged) for the Window which exposes a Uri property as follows:

```
private readonly string _image1 = "pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/MyImage1.jpg";
private readonly string _image2 = "pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/MyImage2.jpg";

public MainNavWindowViewModel()
{
    SetImage1();
}

private Uri _backgroundImg;
public Uri BackgroundImg
{
    get
    {
        return _backgroundImg;
    }
    private set
    {
        _backgroundImg = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("BackgroundImg");
    }
}

public void SetImage1()
{
    BackgroundImg = new Uri(_image1);
}

public void SetImage2()
{
    BackgroundImg = new Uri(_image2);
}
```

In the main window's xaml file, I have replaced the NavigationWindow.Background with:

```
<NavigationWindow.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=BackgroundImg, Mode=OneWay}" />
</NavigationWindow.Background>
```

and set the Windows' DataContext to the ViewModel.

However, this functionality just displays a black background on my window (which is the same behaviour when I comment out the line that databinds the ViewModel to the Window).

I'm setting the ViewModel to the Datacontext in the first line of the Window's constructor. If I put a breakpoint on it, it executes the lines and seems ok.

Any ideas what is going on or how I can work out where it is going wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured out what was going wrong. The image resource's build action was set to Embedded Resources but this should be set to Resources. Unfortunately, doing just a build doesn't always apply the change so a rebuild or clean+build was required.

Answer (score 0):

You're using .NET 3.5?
There's a bug, but you can use a Converter to reach the same effect:

```
Public Class BitmapImageToImageConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim bitmapImage = TryCast(value, BitmapImage)
        Dim height As Double = 0

        Dim returnImage As New Image()

        If bitmapImage IsNot Nothing Then
            returnImage.Height = 15

            If parameter IsNot Nothing AndAlso Double.TryParse(parameter.ToString, height) Then
                returnImage.Height = height
            End If

            returnImage.Source = bitmapImage
        Else
            ' Set a default image if none is given
            Dim uriString = "pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/nopicture.png"

            Dim img As New BitmapImage()
            img.BeginInit()
            img.UriSource = New Uri(uriString)
            img.EndInit()

            returnImage.Source = img
        End If

        Return returnImage
    End Function


    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

Using:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BitmapImageToImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />
```

Image is then a property of System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage in your viewmodel.. to load it I have the following method (this loads an embedded image in /Resources folder:

```
Protected Sub LoadBitmapImageFromResource(ByVal fileName As String)
    Dim assName = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name
    Dim uriString = "pack://application:,,,/" + assName + ";component/Resources/" + fileName

    Dim img As New BitmapImage()
    img.BeginInit()
    img.UriSource = New Uri(uriString)
    img.EndInit()

    Image = img
End Sub
```

The standard height is set to 15 pixels (in my implementation I use my converter for menu items so they are really small ;) ), but you can give an integer value as ConverterParameter which sets the height of the image.

PS: Sorry for VB.NET, but it was a requirement by my customer to wrote this in VB.NET and not in c#...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's no longer an issue now but I was using .Net 4.